# htaccess: Remove PHP extension only for specific files or folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently using the following in /public_html/.htaccess to strip .php extensions and force trailing slashes.

```
# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

This works perfectly, however, there are a number of PHP files in subfolders of /public_html that we don't want to be rewritten.

How can I modify the rewrite + trailing slash to apply only to PHP files in the /public_html folder, or, to specify a list of PHP files that the rule applies to?

**UPDATE:**
In my case, I believe the optimal solution will be to strip the PHP extension (and add trailing slash) only to files explicitly specified, rather than creating folder-based conditions.

**UPDATE 2:**
Working solution:

```
#Remove PHP extension from named files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(file1|file2)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Is your "update 2" in its entirety?

Comment: Yes, that's the entire relevant portion. The actual .htaccess is much longer, but everything else (aside from the obvious `RewriteEngine On` directive) is unrelated to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make an exception at the start of your `.htaccess` file... if the request matches one of these subfolders (*and* is an existing PHP file?) then stop the rewriting process. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(subfolder1|subfolder2)$ - [L]
```

If you simply want to skip all requests then you can stop there. If you specifically need to only skip the rewrites if it matches existing PHP files then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(subfolder1|subfolder2)/.+\.php$ - [L]
```

If the request if for `/subfolder1/<something>.php` and that file exists then stop here.

**UPDATE#1:**

> We only want this to apply to PHP files in /public_html, and none of its subfolders

You could probably still do this with an exception before your existing rules. If the request contains a slash (ie. it's for a subfolder) then abort. For example:

```
RewriteRule /.*/?$ - [L]
```

Alternatively, change the pattern in your existing `RewriteRule`s to match anything except a slash (ie. `[^/]*`) instead of literally everything (ie. `.*`). Applied to your existing rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
:
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ $1.php [L]
:
RewriteRule ^[^/]*$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

**UPDATE#2:** Added anchors to the above `RewriteRule` patterns.

**UPDATE#3:** To make the above apply to only specific files in the document root. You would use an exception (as in the above) that excludes all other files. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^(file1|file2|file3|file4) - [L]
```

In order to allow all URLs that *start* `/file1`, `/file2`, `/file3`, etc. (The URL matched by the `RewriteRule` pattern does not start with a slash in per-directory .htaccess files.)

In context...

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Only allow specific requests to be processed...
RewriteRule !^(file1|file2|file3|file4) - [L]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

# Route request...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I change this so I'm specifying the folders the rule should apply to, rather than the folders it does NOT apply to? We only want this to apply to PHP files in /public_html, and none of its subfolders (of which there are too many to list explicitly if we can avoid it).

Also, what would the full htaccess be in that case? I'm a bit unclear where to place this, as currently the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` is second to last, as part of the force trailing slash code.

Comment: Place any exception "at the start of your `.htaccess` file". You could still use an exception to apply only to requests in the root. Or you change your existing `RewriteRule` _pattern_. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Corrected regex in the first pattern after update

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, neither solution had the desired effect. Here is what I tried: http://pastebin.com/eK3YkrCH

I think the simplest solution in our case would be to explicitly list the PHP files in public_html that this rewrite should apply to (there are only 5). Is this possible?

Comment: What actually happens? Have you cleared your browser cache (or test with caching disabled)? Any earlier/erroneous 301s will have been cached by the browser.

Comment: Yes, I cleared cache and performed a hard refresh for each test. The rewrites worked for the files I wanted them to, but some URLs outside of public_html were also being rewritten, with most of their path being stripped as well. 

There are dozens of subfolders and hundreds of PHP files, and there's also a lack of uniformity in internal linking (ie. some internal links use /, others don't). For peace of mind I think the best solution here is to explicitly name the files the rewrite applies to.

Comment: Updated regex. What URL outside the public_html are being rewritten? Just to clarify, the URLs being linked to in the document root are already canonical. ie. are of the form `/something/`?

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try `RewriteRule !^(file1|file2|file3|file4) - [L]`, but can you show me what the full .htaccess would look like for that solution? Want to make sure I implement correctly.

Comment: That line would simply need to go _before_ the existing mod_rewrite directives.

Comment: Still no luck. Here are the 3 variations I tried: http://pastebin.com/vLLKbH3d I'm afraid that without seeing the full code, I'm not implementing it correctly. I know nothing about regexp or htaccess.

Comment: It's possibly made more complex by the variation in URLs that can be used to access this resource. What URL do you use to access these root files... `/api/`, `/api` or `/api.php` (I assume the first - but all 3 are possible with the directives you have posted). I'll update my answer...

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. All three URLs returned 404 (my.com/api.php, my.com/api, my.com/api/). As to your question, we're linking to the resource as /api

Comment: Just found a working solution. Updating question.

Comment: Make sure `MultiViews` is disabled (updated answer).

Comment: That is the entire rewrite solution, yes. However, it doesn't include forcing a trailing "/". I currently have: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(file1|file2)/$ $0/ [L,R=301]` which is not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I voted your answer even though I went with the simpler solution, however it doesn't show since I have < 15pts. Will try to resolve the forced / issue in another question if needed.